# Number of DB connections breach maximumPoolSize using Hive Metastore + HikariCP

Tags: postgresql, hive, hikaricp, hive-metastore

I am using Presto with Hive Metastore, the latter is configured to use HikariCP and is backed by a Postgres database.

Using default values I observe that the Metastore creates 2x Hikari connection pools, each with maximumPoolSize set to 10.  When everything starts up I see 20 connections to the **metastore** database in Postgres, so far so good.

```
[HikariPool-1 housekeeper] pool.HikariPool: HikariPool-1 - Pool stats (total=10, active=0, idle=10, waiting=0)
[HikariPool-2 housekeeper] pool.HikariPool: HikariPool-2 - Pool stats (total=10, active=0, idle=10, waiting=0)
```

However ... over time, as queries are submitted and clients connect to the Metastore, I see the number of connections in Postgres climb above 20.  I expected the pool size to be fixed and the number of backend DB connections to not exceed 20 i.e. maximumPoolSize (10) x number of pools (2).  Any insight into why this is happening ?

e.g.

```
postgres=# SELECT COUNT(*) from pg_stat_activity where datname = 'metastore';

 count 
-------
    38
(1 row)


postgres=# SELECT COUNT(*) from pg_stat_activity where datname = 'metastore';
 count 
-------
    57
```

**Versions:**

- Hive = 2.3.6
- HikariCP = 2.5.1
- DataNucleus = 4.1.17
- Postgres Server = 12

**HikariConfig:**

```
hikari.HikariConfig: HikariPool-1 - configuration:
hikari.HikariConfig: allowPoolSuspension.............false
hikari.HikariConfig: autoCommit......................true
hikari.HikariConfig: catalog.........................null
hikari.HikariConfig: connectionInitSql...............null
hikari.HikariConfig: connectionTestQuery.............null
hikari.HikariConfig: connectionTimeout...............30000
hikari.HikariConfig: dataSource......................null
hikari.HikariConfig: dataSourceClassName.............null
hikari.HikariConfig: dataSourceJNDI..................null
hikari.HikariConfig: dataSourceProperties............{password=<masked>}
hikari.HikariConfig: driverClassName................."org.postgresql.Driver"
hikari.HikariConfig: healthCheckProperties...........{}
hikari.HikariConfig: healthCheckRegistry.............null
hikari.HikariConfig: idleTimeout.....................600000
hikari.HikariConfig: initializationFailFast..........true
hikari.HikariConfig: isolateInternalQueries..........false
hikari.HikariConfig: jdbc4ConnectionTest.............false
hikari.HikariConfig: jdbcUrl........................."jdbc:postgresql://hive-db:5432/metastore"
hikari.HikariConfig: leakDetectionThreshold..........0
hikari.HikariConfig: maxLifetime.....................1800000
hikari.HikariConfig: maximumPoolSize.................10
hikari.HikariConfig: metricRegistry..................null
hikari.HikariConfig: metricsTrackerFactory...........null
hikari.HikariConfig: minimumIdle.....................10
hikari.HikariConfig: password........................<masked>
hikari.HikariConfig: poolName........................"HikariPool-1"
hikari.HikariConfig: readOnly........................false
hikari.HikariConfig: registerMbeans..................false
hikari.HikariConfig: scheduledExecutorService........null
hikari.HikariConfig: threadFactory...................null
hikari.HikariConfig: transactionIsolation............null
hikari.HikariConfig: username........................"postgres"
hikari.HikariConfig: validationTimeout...............5000

hikari.HikariConfig: HikariPool-2 - configuration:
hikari.HikariConfig: allowPoolSuspension.............false
hikari.HikariConfig: autoCommit......................true
hikari.HikariConfig: catalog.........................null
hikari.HikariConfig: connectionInitSql...............null
hikari.HikariConfig: connectionTestQuery.............null
hikari.HikariConfig: connectionTimeout...............30000
...
...
```

Comment: pg_stat_activity shows other types of processes too.  What is the backend_type for these?

Comment: Can you show the "Pool stats" during these times of high connection counts?

Comment: The backend_type is 'client backend' for all records.  Also, when the count from SELECT COUNT(*) from pg_stat_activity where datname = 'metastore' reaches 100 nothing can connect to postgres, not even psql.  The error is "Error:org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: FATAL: sorry, too many clients already".

Comment: The connection count is high right now - can you please advise how i show 'Pool stats' ?

Comment: Your first code-formatted sections shows pool stats. I don't know how you obtained that, I'm not a HikariCP user.

Comment: Right, that is from the Hive Metastore logs.  And I've never seen anything but what you see there - 2 pools, 10 total per pool